# How to get module name used to show option on admin menu

Tags: module, admin, customer-group

Hi I currently have a very peculiar problem.
Please check the image below.
[image]
I dont know from where the customer group is coming .
I want to find a way to remove this block.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the customer group in backend customer group section. From Admin - Customers - manage customers - customer group where you will find different types of groups.

Comment: NO. There is no option for manage it for admin menu. I checked it.

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The customer groups come from your backend and they can be managed there.
Go to Customers->Customer Groups.

[image: customer groups]

Comment: NO. There is no option for manage it for admin menu. I checked it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the menu item where you can manage customer groups. If that menu is not there, maybe your user does not have access to it.